# How to know absolute position of a SVG PATH?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a SVG generated with InkScape, all PATHs has moveto relative position (m):

```
  <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        style="fill: #07fe01; 
               fill-opacity: 1; 
               display: inline; 
               stroke-width: 4px; 
               cursor: auto; 
               stroke: none; 
               opacity: 0.4; 
               filter: none; " 
         d="m 431.36764,202.65372 -20.46139,7.94003 -2.875,8.84375 -3.0625,13.21875 8.8125,0.96875 13.34375,6.84375 9.94451,-6.04527 11.96344,-1.95225 -2.3183,-6.56201 0.1291,-10.53422 z" 
         id="Rossello" 
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" 

         sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccccc"  xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" 
         transform="translate(-0.03124997,-689.42566)" 
         onclick="mapmed.click(this)" 
         onmouseover="mapmed.over(this)" 
         onmouseout="mapmed.out(this)">
            <title id="title3042">Rosselló</title>
  </path>
```

I need to know the absolute position of each path from javascript, but I can't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to know the absolute position. The mistake was try to find the absolute coords without apply the base layer translate and count pixes like in InkScape, from down to up, and not up to down as in SVG.

Follow this steeps to know the absolute position of the first node of a PATH in pixels:

1st get the width and height of the svg object.  svgWidth, svgHeight.

2nd get the transform translate of the base layout. baseTransX, baseTransY.

3rd get the first node of the path. pathX, pathY.

4th get the transform translate of the path if exists, if not 0. pathTransX, pathTransY.

With this values, we can found absolute X and Y for the first node in InkScape:

X = baseTransX + pathTransX + pathX

Y = svgHeight - (baseTransY + pathTransY + pathY)

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like [normalizedPathSegList](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#InterfaceSVGAnimatedPathData) is what you want.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but trying every method and property normalizedPathSegList always is null

Comment: And Chrome hasn't getNormalizedPathSegList() Uncaught TypeError: Object [object SVGPathElement] has no method 'getNormalizedPathSegList'

Comment: @corretge: that's because it's not yourpath.getNormalizedPathSegList(), it's yourpath.normalizedPathSegList.

Comment: @ErikDahlström trying this I get null, as I say in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
        ele=$('#Rosello')[0]
        var bbox = ele.getBBox()
        var top = bbox.y + bbox.y2
```

The same should work in x-direction.

I am not sure, but I observe that getBBox is pretty slow. So take care.